# Homepage with latest posts does not include current-menu-item

Tags: theme-development

I have selected the following settings in WordPress:

[image]

And created a navigation with two links:

[image]

The *Work* link should link to my homepage which is why I set the URl to */*. This works perfectly fine. Though the *current-menu-item*-class is not added to the element when being on the homepage:

[image]

Is there a correct way of fixing this?

Looking forward to your reply!

Comment: it's probably because it's a custom link, there is a home link block that can be used for the homepage instead

Comment: Hi Tom, I see. Using the home link block works. There is no easy option to rename it or am I mistaking? The only option is to change the label with js?

Comment: I was able to change the label of the home link by clicking on it and typing just like headings and paragraph text, I was even able to apply rich text formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the current menu classes aren't applied based on the URL but instead based on the main query.

For the homepage, instead use a homepage link block:

[image]

You can edit it just link any other nav menu item or paragraph by clicking and typing on it directly:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I think there is an issue with wordpress. I get the blinking text cursor for any other element beside the homepage link block though it is editable as you said.